# How can I periodically update my component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs2, vue.js

I have a component in Vue that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="featured_top">
    <i class="i-cancel close"></i>
    <div v-for="item in toplist">
      <div class="featured-item" v-lazy:background-image="poster(item)">
        <a class="page-link" :href="url(item)" target="_blank">
          <h4 class="type"> Featured Movie </h4>
          <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const _ = require('lodash')

export default {
  name: 'featured',
  computed: {
    toplist () {
      return _.sampleSize(this.$store.state.toplist, 3)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    poster: function (item) {
      return 'https://example.com/' + item.backdrop_path
    },
    url: function (item) {
      return 'http://example.com/' + item.id
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I choose three random items from the store hen rendering the component, iterate over and display then. However, this seems too static so I'd like periodically update the component so it randomises the items again.

I'm new to Vue2 - any ideas on what trivial bit I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please explain issue a bit more ? It's not totally clear to me.You are getting 3 items from store, then in computed property you apply some unknown method for me from lodash and then iterate over it.What you want to achieve ?

Comment: @BelminBedak sorry for not being explicit enough. The accepted answer below illustrates my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use-case is not completely clear to me but if you'd like to randomize with an interval. You could change your computation to a method and call this function with `setInterval`.

Something like in the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/m9hxfmcz/) should work.

(In the demo I've removed the lazy loading of the image to reduce the complexity a bit.)

```js
// const _ = require('lodash')
const testData = _.range(1, 10)
  .map((val) => {
    return {
      title: 'a item ' + val
    }
  })

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      toplist: testData
    }
  })
  //export default {

const randomItems = {
  name: 'featured',
  template: '#tmpl',
  computed: {
    /*toplist () {
      return _.sampleSize(this.$store.state.toplist, 3)
    }*/
  },
  created() {
    this.getToplist() // first run
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getToplist, 2000)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.interval) {
      clearIntervall(this.interval)
      this.interval = undefined
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      interval: undefined,
      toplist: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getToplist() {
        this.toplist = _.sampleSize(this.$store.state.toplist, 3)
      },
      poster: function(item) {
        return 'https://example.com/' + item.backdrop_path
      },
      url: function(item) {
        return 'http://example.com/' + item.id
      }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<div><random-items></random-items</div>',
  store,
  components: {
    randomItems
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.1.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="tmpl">
  <div id="featured_top">
    <i class="i-cancel close"></i>
    <div v-for="item in toplist">
      <div class="featured-item" v-lazy:background-image="poster(item)">
        <a class="page-link" :href="url(item)" target="_blank">
          <h4 class="type"> Featured Movie </h4>
          <div class="title">{{ item.title }}</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. In the process I also learnt about the Vue lifecycle methods. Much appreciated.

Comment: Bad idea. My child component always re-rendering I don't know why, Input file upload will clear immediately after select the file. And the causes is the javascript timer like that. Please help me if you have solution